# Replacement for $Set in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, nestjs

Hello I have small problem with my call to mongoDB.
Im using $set functionality on my localhost, and it works super fine, yet after using it on production enviroment we getting error because mongoDB version is 4.0, we cannot upgrade Database so my question, is there ANY replacement for $Set in version 4.0? can I use anything to achive same call?

Call to mongo:

```html
const templateList = await this.templatesModel.aggregate([
      {
        $facet: {
          data: [
            {
              $lookup:
              {
                from: 'extensions',
                localField: 'extensionName',
                foreignField: 'extension',
                as: 'extension',
              },
            },
            { $unwind: '$extension' },
            { $set: { bundleIds: '$extension.bundle' } },
            { $match: filter },
            { $skip: offset },
            { $limit: limit },
            {
              $project: {
                extensionName: 1,
                isDefault: 1,
                previewImage: 1,
                published: 1,
                title: 1,
                updated: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
          totalCount: [
            {
              $lookup:
              {
                from: 'extensions',
                localField: 'extensionName',
                foreignField: 'extension',
                as: 'extension',
              },
            },
            { $unwind: '$extension' },
            { $set: { bundleIds: '$extension.bundle' } },
            { $match: filter },
            { $count: 'count' },
          ],
        },
      },
    ]).exec();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `$set` with `$addFields`.

Both these stages perform the same task since [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) is nothing but an alias of [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-addFields).